# Unit testing methods requiring user input

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Okay. So I've to do unit test for my application. It inlcudes several `void` methods. In almost every method I have like `OpenFileDialog` or `SaveFileDialog`. How can I test those methods?

P.S Those methods are button events, which require like `(object sender, EventArgs e)` as parameters, which I cannot pass in my testing Class Library

P.S2 I cannot change my project anymore (lecturers requirement)

Comment: Then you cannot fix this. You could have done it through an abstraction like `IFilePicker`, whose implementation uses `OpenFileDialog` and returns a path, which you could then mock.

Comment: What platform are you testing against? WinForm, WPF, UWP...etc?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is event handler :

```
void btn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

You can just call it like this :

```
btn_Click (this.openDialog, new EventArgs())
```

Make sure you make it public in class you try to test.